# Create file and download on button click with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a function which will get the value from textarea and download it as an HTML file.

The HTML file

```
<textarea id="text-val" rows="4"></textarea>
<a href="" id="dwn-btn">Download your Code</a>
```

The Javascript Function

```
function download(filename, html) {
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(html));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);

    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    document.body.removeChild(element);
}


document.getElementById("dwn-btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
            var text = document.getElementById("text-val").value;
    var filename = "MyCode.html";

    download(filename, html);
}, false);
```

My question is : If a user put some external code source in textarea, as an example some image link. How can I download that image too and create a folder like images and put that image inside folder.

```js
function download(filename, text) {
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);

    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    document.body.removeChild(element);
}

// Start file download.
document.getElementById("dwn-btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    // Generate download of hello.txt file with some content
    var text = document.getElementById("text-val").value;
    var filename = "hello.html";
    
    download(filename, text);
}, false);
```

```html
    <textarea id="text-val" rows="4"></textarea>
    <a href="" id="dwn-btn">Download your Code</a>
```

Comment: One way - *(In case of images)* You can find out all the images from the text area and download that to any folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can't download folders inside a browser. Although you might create a zip, either client side or server side, and download that zip

Comment: So how to create a zip file and download all content on button click

Answer (score 0):

I know this code isn't optimized and a bit hacky but you can use it as a starting point.

It converts the image URL into base64 so it can be used inline with the downloaded HTML file.

```js
document.getElementById("dwn-btn").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var content = document.getElementById("text-val").value;

    content.match(/(src=".+"|src='.+')/g).forEach(function(match) {
      var imageURL = match.substring(5).slice(0, -1);
      var imageElem = document.createElement("img");

      toDataURL(imageURL, function(dataUrl) {
        var regex = new RegExp(imageURL);
        content = content.replace(regex, dataUrl);
      });
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
      var blob = new Blob([content], {type: "text/html"});
      var link = document.createElement("a");

      link.download = "mydownloadedcode.html";
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click"));
    }, 2000);
  });

  function toDataURL(src, callback, outputFormat) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function() {
      var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var dataURL;
      canvas.height = this.naturalHeight;
      canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
      ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
      dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
      callback(dataURL);
    };
    img.src = src;
    if (img.complete || img.complete === undefined) {
      img.src = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==";
      img.src = src;
    }
  }
```

```html
<textarea id="text-val" rows="4">
  <img id="imageid" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d50c83cc0c6523b4d3f6085295c953e0">
  <img id="imageid" src='https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d50c83cc0c6523b4d3f6085295c953e0'>
</textarea>
<a href="" id="dwn-btn">Download your Code</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this URL, might be your issue solved

https://viralpatel.net/blogs/create-zip-file-javascript/

https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-zip